# Python Altair Display only some labels and ticks at x-axis

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

i have a data frame with dates and values. On x-axis I just want to display the labels and ticks for specific months, e.g. if month = october. Here is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

dates = np.arange('2016-02', '2023-09', dtype='datetime64[M]')
val = np.linspace(1,1.4,num=len(dates ))

df= pd.DataFrame({
  "date": pd.to_datetime(dates ),
  "val": val
    })

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
       x = alt.X("date:T", axis = alt.Axis(title = None, grid = False, format = "%b %y")),
       y = alt.Y("val", axis = alt.Axis(title = None, format='%'))
    )
```

How can I handle this with altair, any suggestions?

I tried a lot with labelExpr, something like

```
labelExpr = alt.condition('timeFormat(datum.value, '%m') == '10' ?, alt.datum.label, ""')
```

but it doesn't work.